# facebook graph API send image message: "failed to fetch the file from the url"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, imageurl

Since 2018-02-22, I cannot send messages with images I uploaded to S3 to Facebook anymore.

I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Failed to fetch the file from the url","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":2018008,"fbtrace_id":"BP8L9CQBKP+"}}
```

Here is my test set-up:

```
TOKEN=<a_valid_page_token>
FBUSER=<an_fb_user_id>
URL=https://airy-layer-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/images/fd9aee26-7dd5-48cb-99c9-c4f10ec38f31.png

curl -H"Content-Type: application/json" https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=$TOKEN \
     -d'{"recipient":{"id":"'$FBUSER'"},"message":{"attachment":{"type":"image","payload":{"url": "'$URL'"}}}}'
```

These URL all work fine

```
URL=http://rtens.org/images/avatar.jpg
URL=https://visualhunt.com/photos/s/4/anime-pet-kitty.jpg
URL=https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-blog/assets/puppy-7_zps26e8a8d9.jpg
URL=https://smd-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/science-pink/s3fs-public/styles/front_page_hero_image/public/thumbnails/image/deer_duo.jpg
```

I've made sure that the images exist, are publicly available, and <2MB. The images are uploaded the same way as before 2018-02-22. Why does Facebook fail to fetch the file?

Thank you for your help,
Nikolas

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by disabling base64 encoding when uploading the image to S3.